# Unity3d pipe connection

Tags: unity-game-engine, named-pipes

I am trying to make a simple pipe connection with my robot controller program, which will be the client(sending data), and my program in Unity3d, which will be the server(receiving data).

In unity,

```
string pipeName = "trypipe";
var server2 = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipeName);
long length = server2.Length;
byte[] buffer = new byte[length+ 10];
int offset = (int)length;
int count = 0;


server2.WaitForConnection();
server2.Read(buffer, offset, count);
server2.Close();
```

In my controller program,

```
string pipeName = "trypipe";
NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(pipeName);
pipeClient.Connect();
pipeClient.WriteByte(1);
pipeClient.Close();
```